# Como acessar registros de um CMS de um local acima de onde ele está instalado?

Tags: php, twig, cms

Utilizo o `CMS Bolt` e ele utiliza o `Twig`, template engine. Estou precisando acessar o conteúdo criado, em uma página acima de onde o `CMS` está rodando.

> Ex: Bolt instalado na pasta blog; página pra acessar e mostrar o
>   conteúdo está na teste, de local "teste/blog".

Na página normal de blog estou usando essas chamadas:

```
{% setcontent records = "entries/latest/2" allowpaging %}
{% for record in records %}
   <div class="four columns thumb" style="margin-left: 0px; clear: both";>
      {% if record.image!="" %}
      <img src="{{ thumbnail(record.image, 100, 100) }}" alt="thumbnail" class="u-max-full-width">
      {% endif %}
   </div>
   <div class="eight columns">
      <small class="date">{{ record.datecreated|date("d.m.y") }}</small>
      <p><a href="{{ record.link }}" class="footer_last_blog">{{ record.excerpt(75) }}</a></p>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: O que você já tem feito?
Já tem alguma configuração? @EmanuelBarbosaGonçalves

Comment: Sei como fazer o acesso normalmente pela pasta "blog", nos arquivos que estão contidos nela. Mas não sei como puxar as informações, os registros, através de um nível acima dessa pasta. Tem como eu acessar as funções ou chamadas do CMS e eles me retornarem o valor que eu quero pra esse arquivo que está acima de onde está o CMS?

Comment: Editei e coloquei de como tenho feito

Comment: Alguém? Por favor?